# Terraform filter data source if tag doesn't exist

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to filter an `aws_subnet` data source, and one of the criteria is that a `tag` does not exist.

```
data "aws_subnet" "selected" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:environment"
    values = ["foobar"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "tag:thistagdoesnotexist"
    values = [""]
  }
}
```

Is this possible? and if not, is there a potential workaround without adding the `tag` to every resource?

Comment: Yes, you can add tags to all resources by using `default_tags` option: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/resource-tagging#propagating-tags-to-all-resources. Note that there are some resources for which this does not work but it should work for subnets and VPCs.

Comment: Whether this is available intrinsically depends upon the current AWS API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeSubnets.html. It appears the answer is: no. Typical filtering through the AWS API is on tag values and not keys, so that is why this is not available natively.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get resources with a different tag value (still not quite what OP is looking for, but close) - get all resources, get  resources with a particular tag value, then subtract the tagged resources from all resources.

```
data "aws_security_groups" "all" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.prod_info.id]
  }
}

data "aws_security_groups" "tagged" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.prod_info.id]
  }
  tags = {
     foo = "bar"
   }
}

locals {
  differently_tagged = setsubtract(data.aws_security_groups.all.ids, data.aws_security_groups.tagged.ids)
}
```

Then the untagged resources are available as `local.differently_tagged`.

Again, not quite the same thing as the tag not existing, but would help in the scenario where there are a bunch of resources all with the same tag value, and the rest are untagged.